# How can we find out ordered grouped product ID on magento

Tags: php, magento, product

I am having many grouped products on a store. Client wants to see grouped product detail also on the ordered item section but in magento it shows only simple products on the items list. How can we get the grouped product details in the grouped product ordering. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::getParentItem()`
?
or equivalent - `$item->getParentItem()` ?